# vstest.console.exe ListTests with FullyQualifiedName

Tags: vstest, vstest.console.exe, vstest.console

**/ListTests** option of vstest is returning a list of test method names inside a dll.

Is there a way to return a list of **FullyQualifiedNames**?

So instead of getting **TestMethodName** I would like to receive **NamespaceName**.**ClassName**.**TestMethodName**.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following command:
`vstest.console a.dll /ListFullyQualifiedTests /ListTestsTargetPath:Tests.txt`