# How to get the number of tests without running them and with minimum text parsing using vstest.console.exe?

Tags: mstest, vstest, vstest.console.exe

I have the following command line working:

```
dotnet vstest ...\Platform.UnitTests.dll -lt
```

And it does show the available tests:

```
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.9.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The following Tests are available:
    UnitTests.KeyGenerationTests.GenerationServiceTests.GenerateLongTest(min: -9223372036854775807, max: 3722052250456372)
    UnitTests.KeyGenerationTests.GenerationServiceTests.GenerateLongTest(min: 0, max: 2818886159009824)
    UnitTests.KeyGenerationTests.GenerationServiceTests.GenerateLongTest(min: 1234, max: 3070940396521188)
    UnitTests.KeyGenerationTests.GenerationServiceTests.GenerateLongTest(min: -4544123, max: 6717503777496228)
```

So, I can get the count with the following Powershell command line:

```
(dotnet vstest ...\Platform.UnitTests.dll -lt | Select-Object -Skip 4 | Measure-Object -Line).Lines
```

But is it the best way?

E.g. with NUnit I can get an xml file listing all the test cases and counting certain nodes (using XPath) gives us the count of NUnit test cases. I like this one much more, because it does not require me to parse the command output.

So, the question is - can we get the count of tests with vstest.console.exe without parsing the output?

P.S.

Purists might indicate that reading XML involves parsing it. I am fine with that kind of parsing.

Comment: Maybe something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46939985/7225096. You will have to read text file, but you won't have to parse output.

Comment: I ended up using `dotnet vstest $TestDll --ListTests $WhereArg --nologo` and counting the output lines (need to subtract 1)

Answer (score 1):

To clarify: not a full answer, but, in my case I wanted to find a way of checking for an **absence of tests** as part of an Azure DevOps pipeline (using `dotnet test` as part of a bash script).

```
dotnet test MySolution.sln --list-tests --verbosity=quiet --nologo | wc -l
```

The flags I used were `list-tests` to display the list of tests, `verbosity=quiet` and `nologo` flag (for good measure) to hide the junk, and piped the output into linux wordcount (`wc`), with the `-l` flag to count the number of lines.

This results in an output of 0 if there are **no tests**. If there **are tests**, then the count will be wrong as there is still some verbose output -therefore this solution will not offer a count of tests as per the questions, but may help anyone who stumbles across this question (as I did) whilst looking to check for a lack of tests.

Comment: piping through `grep "^    "` is a massive hack but works because the test lines are all indented.